# Fake Call and message

Tags: android, phone-call

Can anyone help me how to create a fake call.

as same mobile I want to create a fake name or number and fix timing : Example

```
5sec.(here i am using the toggle button enable disable fake call)
```

Comment: What do you mean by a fake call?

Comment: i need to create a incoming call like real. but this call can attend but no one speak because this is an fake. in your application need to create a call function. when we have enable the fake call we have to fill phone number or name.when we have receiving that call that number or name will be displayed. but no one has call us.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create fake calls. You could pretend that it is a call by re-creating the look of dialing screen in your application and show it when you need to fake the call, but you cannot fool (perhaps it **might** be doable on rooted devices, but I assume you target regular devices) the system and make system dialer (or replacement) to think there's a call while there's not.